# How display XML code on html

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml

I have file examle.xml:

```
<tag> 
    <tag1>example</tag1>
</tag>
```

I get this file:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
var response = xhr.responseXML;
```

and i want display on html just xml tree,
result on HTML site:

```
<tag> 
    <tag1>example</tag1>
</tag>
```

Comment: It can be `<code>your xml here</code>` or `<pre>` tag

Comment: @john i try create element 'code' from js and append it as a child to document body, but it displays on html "[object XMLDocument]"

Comment: You can use the responseText instead of responseXML and feed it to some pretty printer library like http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thx, its work when i make tag in html, but if i make pre in js text is not colored